# Spritely jQuery plugin and the pan() method

Tags: jquery

OK, I'm trying to include some animating backgrounds using Spritely as a test on my website but I'm having some problems.

For some reason, I cannot get the background to pan correctly.

I use this jQuery in my document ready event handler:

```
$('#bg_1').pan({fps: 30, speed: 2, dir: 'right'});
```

And then firebug gives me the following error:

```
$("#bg_1").pan is not a function
```

Now, this should work considering my JS spritely file appears to be linked properly.

If you would like to view the problem live here is the site URL:
http://www.marioplanet.com

Any ideas as to why pan() isn't recognized as a function?

Comment: I don't really want to answer my own question because I'm not sure if that's how this should work, but for some reason I have found that it was a problem with the .js file itself, and I swapped the compressed version for the full version and it worked for some reason xD

Comment: You should add that there's a problem with the compressed version as an answer, it'll help the next person with the same issue that finds this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK everyone, for those that have this problem in the future here is what I have found:

For some reason, the compressed version of the Spritely jQuery plugin had a problem, as when I called the pan() method, it wasn't recognized as a function.

For some reason, downloading the full, uncompressed version instead of the compressed made it work beautifully!

Check out the effect here, it's pretty sick, and really easy to do! :)
http://www.marioplanet.com